# Get Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get' when i try to display data in template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am running into the issue of getting Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'get' when i try to display data in a template here are the different backbone parts:

Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="class-template">


                <table class="table striped"></table>

                <thead>

                <tr>

                <th>Picture</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Email</th>


                </tr>

                </thead>

                <tbody>

                <% _.each(users,function(user){ %>

                <tr>
                <td><%= user.get('picUrl') %></td>
                <td><%= user.get('firstName') %></td>
                <td><%= user.get('lastLame') %></td>
                <td><%= user.get('role') %></td>
                <td><%= user.get('email') %></td>




                </tr>

                <% }); %>

                </tbody>
                  </table>

    </script>
```

Data Models and Collection:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {

        options.url = 'http://localhost/' +options.url;

        });

        var Office = Backbone.Model.extend({

            defaults: {
                street : null,
                city : null,
                state : null, 
                country : null,
                postal_code : null,
            },
            initialize: function(){
                console.log("==> NEW LOCATION");

                // you can add event handlers here...


            }
        });
         var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

            defaults: {
                picURL : null,
                firstName : null,
                lastName : null, 
                email : null,
                role : null,
                location : new Office()
            },
            initialize: function(){
                console.log("==> NEW PERSON MODEL");

                // you can add event handlers here...


            }
        });

        var Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        url:'loadData.php?list=16025,28477,28474,25513,16489,58911,04607',
        model:Person

        });
```

View:

```
var ShowClass = Backbone.View.extend({

            el: '.page',
            initialize: function() {
                _.bindAll(this); //Make all methods in this class have `this` bound to this class
            },

            template: _.template($('#class-template').html()),

            render: function() {

                var users = new Users();

                console.log('calling fetch');

                users.fetch();

                users.on("reset", function(users){
                    console.log('rendering with data:'+users.models[0].get('firstName'));
                    this.$el.html(this.template({users:users.models}));
                    console.log('finished');
                }, this);

            }

            });
```

I am able to see the data that is returned from the fetch call, so i know that I am getting data back. It all seems to fall apart when i send it to the template. Thanks in advance for all of your help!

Comment: Did you get `users` where you are using it? Or write your `script` before you are using it.

Comment: I add a debugger statement like this: http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1837

Comment: i added console logs to the template and they never run, it looks like the error might be somewhere in the call

Answer (score 1):

Instead of performing the get() on your script template, you should just pass the raw attributes as oppose to passing in the entire model.

I realize that you also have to change your template but abstracting your template this way and doing the loop outside the template itself would give you a better handle on your error. This will also make your code modular and easier to debug.

View:

```
users.on("reset", function(users){
    _.each(users, function (user) {
        var data = user.toJSON();
        this.$el.html(this.template({
                        picUrl: data.picUrl, 
                        firstName: data.firstName }));
    }, this);
```

The template would simply be:

```
<td><%- picUrl %></td>
<td><%- firstName %></td>
...
```

Comment: I'm afraid this would leave the `$el` with the collection's last user's html in it.

Comment: Not if you empty() the content before the render occurs.

Comment: wouldn't it run the template many times and a new table each time it ran?

Comment: You can use `this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);` so `View` is only refreshed and created when a `Model` is changed. This is also a good reason to create a main `Collection` view and another view for each `Model` so you can only act on specific `Model` changes.

Comment: For your template being ran many times, I'd look into precompiling them (not necessarily server-side). What I usually do is to create an array and store the precompiled template ahead of time so I can just call the precompiled function when needed.